# MongoDB Query Won't Sum with Group or Project

Tags: json, mongodb

I cannot for the life of me figure out why my mongo query won't sum this field. If I use $project, it gives me all of the values of the query for individual rows, but once I group it just comes back as 0.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6XMv.png

Comment: Share Source documents as pretty formatted text instead of image

Comment: we cannot for the life of us figure out, what you want without giving us sample data in JSON text and the expected output in JSON text.